# Unable to use External-MQTT Node of Edge's rule engine to send MQTT data as a thing to AWS IoT

Tags: rule-engine, thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

**Component**

- Rule Engine

**Description**
I want to use *'External - mqtt'* Node in rules engine of Thingsboard Edge to send data as an AWS Thing to IoT Core/Greengrass.

I have uploaded certificates (Server Cert, Device cert) and key (Private Key) to the node but I receive no error or debug messages.

Can someone please help me on this.

**Environment**

- OS:  Ubuntu on EC2 Instance
- ThingsBoard Server: 3.6.3
- Thingsboard Edge: 3.6.3
- Browser: Chrome Version 123.0.6312.60 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Not able to send data to AWS IoT via Edge's External-MQTT Rule engine node.